# BigQuery: Aggregate array of objects. Getting "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
id       | teamlead_ids       | Name  
1        | "2, 3"             | Saelesrep_John
2        |                    | Teamlead_Steve
3        |                    | Teamlead_Karl
4        | "2"                | Salesrep_Buck
```

I'm trying to aggregate data about teamleads to have JSON output with array of objects.
Here is how I'm trying to achieve this. I've tried several other options, neither worked. I think this one is the best example:

```
SELECT
  id,
  (SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT STRUCT(
        teamlead.name AS name,
        teamlead.id AS customId
      )
    )
    FROM tables.users teamlead
    WHERE id IN UNNEST(SPLIT(user.teamlead_ids))
  ) AS teamLead
FROM tables.users
```

The result I want:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  teamLead: [{
    customId: 2,
    name: 'Teamlead_Steve'
  }, {
    customId: 3,
    name: 'Teamlead_Karl'
  }]
}, ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The almost similar - but with data - query:

```sql
WITH users AS (
   SELECT "1" id, "2,3" teamlead_ids, "Saelesrep_John" Name  
   UNION ALL SELECT "2", NULL, "Teamlead_Steve"
   UNION ALL SELECT "3", NULL, "Teamlead_Kark"
   UNION ALL SELECT "4", "2", "Salesrep_Buck"
)

SELECT
  id,
  (SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT STRUCT(
        teamlead.name AS name,
        teamlead.id AS customId
      )
    )
    FROM users teamlead
    WHERE id IN UNNEST(SPLIT(user.teamlead_ids))
  ) AS teamLead
FROM users user
```

Produces this error:

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

To fix it, use `ARRAY_AGG()` instead of `ARRAY()`:

```sql
WITH users AS (
   SELECT "1" id, "2,3" teamlead_ids, "Saelesrep_John" Name  
   UNION ALL SELECT "2", NULL, "Teamlead_Steve"
   UNION ALL SELECT "3", NULL, "Teamlead_Kark"
   UNION ALL SELECT "4", "2", "Salesrep_Buck"
)

SELECT
  id,
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG((
      SELECT STRUCT(
        teamlead.name AS name,
        teamlead.id AS customId
      )
    ))
    FROM users teamlead
    WHERE id IN UNNEST(SPLIT(user.teamlead_ids))
  ) AS teamLead
FROM users user
```

---

**Update**: As noted in the comments, this worked with `WITH` tables, but not with a physical one.

This query moves the `UNNEST()` out to get the desired results - with a physical table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE temp.users AS (
   SELECT "1" id, "2,3" teamlead_ids, "Saelesrep_John" Name  
   UNION ALL SELECT "2", NULL, "Teamlead_Steve"
   UNION ALL SELECT "3", NULL, "Teamlead_Kark"
   UNION ALL SELECT "4", "2", "Salesrep_Buck"
)
;



SELECT
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG( (
    SELECT STRUCT(teamlead.name AS name, teamlead.id AS customId)
    FROM temp.users teamlead 
    WHERE user_team_lead = teamlead.id
  ) IGNORE NULLS) AS teamLead
FROM temp.users LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(teamlead_ids)) user_team_lead
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

[image]

Comment: yep, that works. Why does it work only with "WITH", but not with a table? When i'm using `FROM tables.users` (from a permanent table) instead of `FROM users` (from `WITH users AS ...`), it throws this error:
`Query error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join`

Comment: Fixed, see above

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT u.id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(customId, l.name)) teamLead
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(teamlead_ids)) customId
LEFT JOIN users l ON customId = l.id
GROUP BY id
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - result is

```
Row id  teamLead.customId   teamLead.name    
1   1   2                   Teamlead_Steve   
        3                   Teamlead_Karl    
2   2   null                null     
3   3   null                null     
4   4   2                   Teamlead_Steve
```